# Grails - Different date between seleted and saved

Tags: grails, timezone, audit-logging

I have a Grails 2.5.6 app developed with Java 1.8 running in a Docker container. While app was in development I defined time zone in `Bootstrap.groovy` as follows:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/La_Paz"))
```

This is the problem: I select a date in my form, let's say 11/05/2021. Then I checked in the database that the date was saved as `2021-05-11 00:00:00`, which is correct. But the show view shows date as 10/05/2021. Date is even retrieved as 10/05/2021 when I call the edit form. So, if I update the record, date is saved as 10/05/2021.

What could be wrong?

PD: I'm using Audit Logging too, could it be the cause?

Comment: You are correct that it’s a time zone issue. What is the data type used in the database? Which brand of DBMS (database engine) are you using? How do you save the date?

Comment: I am using MySql 5.7 and DATETIME as data type for dates. The applicaton CRUD is implemented with the Grails default scaffolding .

Answer (score 1):

Running the docker container with the following line solved the problem:

```
docker run -d -e JAVA_OPTS='-Duser.timezone=America/La_Paz' -p 8091:8080 mycontainer
```

Sending the JAVA_OPTS parameter did the trick.